# Change sendmail sender using bash

Tags: bash, sendmail

Running the sendmail command I usually get emails with sender like `username@hostname`.

Is there a way to send emails using sendmail and having the sender set to something different from the user account used to run the command?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What you're looking for is `-f`:

```
sendmail -F "Your name" -f "your-address@example.com" < your-message.txt
```

From the [sendmail man page](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html):

```
 -Ffullname  Set the full name of the sender.

 -fname      Sets the name of the ``from'' person (i.e., the sender of the
             mail).  -f can only be used by ``trusted'' users (normally
             root, daemon, and network) or if the person you are trying to
             become is the same as the person you are.
```